# Amazon MWS update product using _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_ / Product feed

Tags: amazon-mws

I want to update the ShippingWeight in some of our products.

I think the Product feed should do this for me.

The feed below seems to work fine, the data is updated in amazon, but I get an error response.

What's wrong with the feed, why do I get an error response even though the updates are done ?

I tried Update and PartialUpdate.

The error response looks like an error on creating new products.

And why do I have to specify the "Title" element when updating the ShippingWeight (Title does not have minOccurs="0" in xsd) :-(

Here's my feed:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>xxxx</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <Message>
    <MessageID>1375606841671</MessageID>
    <OperationType>PartialUpdate</OperationType>
    <Product>
        <SKU>1894</SKU>
        <DescriptionData>
            <Title><![CDATA[abcdefghi....]]></Title>
            <ItemDimensions>
                <Length unitOfMeasure="CM">44.0</Length>
                <Width unitOfMeasure="CM">33.0</Width>
                <Height unitOfMeasure="CM">42.0</Height>
                <Weight unitOfMeasure="GR">1030.0</Weight>
            </ItemDimensions>
            <ShippingWeight unitOfMeasure="GR">1040.0</ShippingWeight>
        </DescriptionData>
    </Product>
</Message>
```

Here's amazon's response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>xxxxxx</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>ProcessingReport</MessageType>
<Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <ProcessingReport>
        <DocumentTransactionID>yyyyy</DocumentTransactionID>
        <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
        <ProcessingSummary>
            <MessagesProcessed>1</MessagesProcessed>
            <MessagesSuccessful>0</MessagesSuccessful>
            <MessagesWithError>1</MessagesWithError>
            <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
        </ProcessingSummary>
        <Result>
            <MessageID>1375606841671</MessageID>
            <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
            <ResultMessageCode>8560</ResultMessageCode>
            <ResultDescription>SKU 1894, Fehlende Attribute product_type. SKU 1894 keine eindeutige ASIN gefunden. Zur Erstellung einer neuen ASIN fehlen noch folgende Attribute: product_type. Feed ID: 0. Weitere Informationen dazu http://sellercentral.amazon.de/gp/errorcode/200692370</ResultDescription>
            <AdditionalInfo>
                <SKU>1894</SKU>
            </AdditionalInfo>
        </Result>
    </ProcessingReport>
</Message>
```

Thanx a lot in advance.

Comment: Adding a <StandardProductID> element with amazon's ASIN and the error has gone. Solved.

Comment: I'm surprised by this because the <StandardProductID> field is for GTINs (UPC, EAN, ISBN). I have this message working with just my seller SKU.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bad SKU number. You can not send in request fiction SKU number. I found some and tried to use RO7WA11930KB1CA1A - hat.